# Create negative space

Tags: adobe-illustrator

currently trying my first experience with Illustrator and I came across a minor issue. I have a shape and path going through that plane which is partly enclosed. Now I want to paint the enclosed path in white but can't seem to figure out how.

This is my current pic:
[image: negative filled]

This is the shape without the path
[image: shape only]

This is only the path
[image: path only]

I want the little loop at the top to be white and the rest of not any color only the stroke itself should be seen. How would I achieve that? I tried Pathfiinder > Subtract but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

- Select the path
- Get the **Shape Builder Tool**  [image: Shape Builder Tool]

  and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to delete, click inside the loop area.

[image: path]

- To keep this shape, just click with the **Shape Builder Tool**

Comment: It's worth noting that you can also use the Pathfinder menu. In this case, however, the Shape Builder Tool is the cleaner and faster option!